# simple awk string comparison unexpected result

Tags: awk

In general string comparison, "A" > "a" is false.

However, I am getting unexpected result from this awk execution:

```
$ echo "A a"| awk '{if ($1 > $2) print "gt"; else print "leq"}'
gt
```

What am I missing?

Environment info:

```
$ uname -r -s -v -M
AIX 1 6 IBM,9110-510

$ locale
LANG=en_AU.8859-15
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.8859-15"
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.8859-15"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.8859-15"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.8859-15"
LC_TIME="en_AU.8859-15"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.8859-15"
LC_ALL=
```

Diagnostics:

```
$ echo "A a"| awk '{print NF}'
2
```

**Update** It produces the correct result after setting LC_ALL=POSIX (thanks JS웃). Need to investigate further into this.

Comment: How do I find out awk version? Thanks.

Comment: `$ awk --version
awk: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: awk [-u] [-F Character][-v Variable=Value][-f File|Commands][Variable=Value|File ...]`. Any idea?

Comment: I get leq (as expected), so it seems to be something about AIX or the data you're passing in. Any chance that you've creating your 'A' in an editing environment that uses Unicode? Just a guess. Else try other comparisons like `1 2` to see if it is specific to chars, or completely broken. Good luck.

Comment: `1 2` are fine. How do I check if the environment uses unicode? What implication does this have?

Comment: Can you type `locale` on your prompt and update the results in your question?

Comment: Can you try `echo "A a"| awk -vFS=' ' '{if ($1 > $2) print "gt"; else print "leq"}'`?

Comment: what do you get for: `echo "A a"| awk '{print NF}'`

Comment: @ettan Can you do `export LC_ALL=POSIX` and try again please

Comment: It works after setting LC_ALL=POSIX. Thanks. Can you please explain what my problem was?

Comment: @ettan Thats great. I am guessing your current `locale` was messed up. I updated the answer for anyone who runs into similar issue again.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce this but you can force a string comparison by concatenating the operand with the null string:

```
echo "A a"| awk '{if ($1"" > $2"") print "gt"; else print "leq"}'
```

**Note:** *Concatenating with any one operand should suffice.*

#### Update:

As suspected the `locale` settings of OP were causing the issue. After setting `LC_ALL=POSIX` the issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you @shellter. Debugging is a great way of learning new things. :)